# Proof that $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\tan$ are well-defined in terms of triangles

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

We all know the elementary school definition of the trigonometric functions: In a right triangle, $\cos$ is defined to be the ratio of the adjacent and the hypotenuse, etc.

But, I observed that this definition has one "problem": For a given angle, there are *infinitely many* right triangles having that angle. How does one prove that the ratio
$$\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$
is *independent* of the right triangle used? The same goes for the other ratios.

Proving the "opposite direction" seems easy: the angle between vectors $u$ and $v$ is
$$\arccos \frac{u\cdot v}{|u||v|}$$
and if the vectors $u'$ and $v'$ are constant multiples of $u$ and $v$, respectively, then we see that the common factor cancels out nicely in the $\arccos$ formula.

Comment: *"How does one prove that the ratio [...] is independent of the right triangle used?"* By showing that triangles with *equal* corresp angles have *proportional* corresp sides, and vice-versa. As [this answer notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3456977/409), Euclid proved the equivalence in [Prop 4](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI4.html) and [Prop 5](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI5.html) of Book 6 of *Elements*. Also, rt triangles sharing an acute angle have all corresp angles equal, as any triangle's angle-sum is $180^\circ$.

Comment: Importantly, this kind of thing only works in Euclidean geometry. In non-Euclidean (ie, "hyperbolic" and "spherical") geometries, there is no universal angle-sum; thus, right triangles sharing an acute angle need not share their other acute angle. Moreover, in these geometries, AAA joins SSS, SAS, and ASA as a *congruence* pattern, so if both acute angles match, then those right triangles are *identical*. As a result, ratios in right triangles do not —*can* not— form the basis of non-Euclidean trig.

Comment: In three words: the intercept theorem. It's an important theorem in Euclidean geometry describing the conditions of similarity (which is the property responsible for the independence of trig ratios to the sizes of the triangles used)